Python JetBrains profiler fallthrough call a lot of time
I test the profiler in the JetBrains software for my Python application. I did that to evaluate the slow part of my code. Problem is, I check the statistics and I see that fallthrough appear 125 times for 6466ms !

I can't find which function call this, do you have any idea ?
Thanks
